# Compare the results of a ROW COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 databases in the same server and I need to compare the registers on each one, since one of the databases is not importing all the information

I was trying to do a ROW count but it's not working

Currently I am doing packages of 100,000 rows approximate, and lookup at them in Excel.

Let's say I want a query that does a count for each ID in TABLE A and then compares the count result VS TABLE B count for each ID, since they are the same ID the count should be the same, and I want that brings me the ID on which there where any mismatch between counts.

Comment: If you state your code isn't working, and don't show your code then we (the **volunteers** here) cannot show you why that code does not work. None of the below answers address the code you have that isn't working, because we (again, the volunteers you're asking for help from), can't see said code. *Note: I'm afraid, as well, due to SO's recent "stance" on pronouns you can't assume people's genders; rather than "Sir" you now need to keep to gender neutral terms or the User's name/alias unless the User asks you otherwise. Text using non-gender neutral language may be removed.*

Comment: "It's not working" will not help us help you.  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--this table will contain the count of occurences of each ID in tableA
declare @TableA_Results table(
ID bigint,
Total bigint
)
insert into @TableA_Results 
select ID,count(*) from database1.TableA
group by ID
--this table will contain the count of occurences of each ID in tableB
declare @TableB_Results table(
ID bigint,
Total bigint
);
insert into @TableB_Results 
select ID,count(*) from database2.TableB
group by ID
--this table will contain the IDs that doesn't have the same amount in  both tables 

declare @Discordances table(
ID bigint,
TotalA bigint,
TotalB bigint
)
insert into @Discordances
select TA.ID,TA.Total,TB.Total
from @TableA_Results TA
inner join @TableB_Results TB on TA.ID=TB.ID and TA.Total!=TB.Total
--the final output
select * from @Discordances
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did?

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague, but maybe this SQL Code might help nudge you in the right direction.

It grabs the IDs and Counts of each ID from database one, the IDs and counts of IDs from database two, and compares them, listing out all the rows where the counts are DIFFERENT.

```
WITH DB1Counts AS (
    SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS CountOfIDs
    FROM DatabaseOne.dbo.TableOne
    GROUP BY ID
), DB2Counts AS (
    SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS CountOfIDs
    FROM DatabaseTwo.dbo.TableTwo
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT a.ID, a.CountOfIDs AS DBOneCount, b.CountOfIDs AS DBTwoCount
  FROM DB1Counts a
       INNER JOIN DB2Counts b ON a.ID = b.ID
 WHERE a.CountOfIDs <> b.CountOfIDs
```

This SQL selects from the specific IDs using the "Database.Schema.Table" notation. So replace "DatabaseOne" and "DatabaseTwo" with the names of your two databases. And of course replace TableOne and TableTwo with the names of your tables (I'm assuming they're the same). This sets up two selects, one for each database, that groups by ID to get the count of each ID. It then joins these two selects on ID, and returns all rows where the counts are different.

Answer (score 1):

You could `full outer join` two aggregate queries and pull out `id`s that are either missing in one table, or for which the record count is different:

```
select coalesce(ta.id, tb.id), ta.cnt, tb.cnt
from 
    (select id, count(*) cnt from tableA) ta
    full outer join (select id, count(*) cnt from tableB) tb
        on ta.id = tb.id
where 
    coalesce(ta.cnt, -1) <> coalesce(tb.cnt, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want aggregation and a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, a.cnt, b.cnt
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from a
      group by id
     ) a full join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from b
      group by id
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id
where coalesce(a.cnt, 0) <> coalesce(b.cnt, 0);
```